# How to disassemble pinned sprockets from a freewheel

Tags: freewheel, sprocket

I have a shimano freewheel like this one

[image]

*Picture taken from [Cassette Removal & Installation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9KAaP7pbFV0)*

I need to use separate sprockets from it but I'm not sure how to extract them without causing any damage. I got the urge to just drill through those pins but I thought I'd rather ask first before the damage is done.

How do you take apart the sprockets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do you take apart the sprockets?

This is not a freeweel but rather a cassette.

By removing the pins, by drilling or angle-grinding them away. This won't cause any damage. You will have your cassette, but with loose sprockets and spacers.

However, do note the sprockets are matched to the neighboring ones in Shimano hyperglide (HG) cassettes. If you customize your cassette, then the matching doesn't work anymore and your shifting suffers. It is not a fatal deficiency, because bicycles were ridden for decades without neighbor-matched side-cut sprockets.

Comment: I assumed it is called a freewheel because of the video that I also linked, they guy clearly says "this is not a cassete system, it is a freewheel system". I'm going to use the sprockets in a completely different application, not a bike. Thank you!

Comment: The head of the rivet holds the bunch. Just drill it away very carefully. (In the early days of HG-cassettes there were small hex-screws, maybe you can find one of these cassettes for your purpose.)